# How do i change the Coveo configuration for Sitecore in an existing setup

Tags: coveo

I have copied an existing Sitecore/Coveo setup from the test environment to my local machine. How do I change the Coveo for Sitecore configuration like *Search API Url*, *Application Secret Key*, *Admin Service Configuration* etc

Changing directly on the config files is enough? I think this also would be stored somewhere on the DB right? what is the right way of doing it?

Answer (score 3):

If you are using a recent version of Coveo for Sitecore you may be able to change some config values by using the **[Coveo Command-Center](https://hls-consulting.com/2019/01/04/coveo-for-sitecore-5-a-new-era-has-begun-the-era-of-the-command-center-part-ii/)**. For other config values such as the SearchAPI URL, you will need to update the config file directly.

Most of the configurations you want to change will be under `App_Config/Include/Coveo/Coveo.CloudPlatformClient.Custom.config` and `App_Config/Include/Coveo/Coveo.SearchProvider.Custom.config`.

If you are trying to bring the configurations you have from one environment to another, just make sure you are copying every Coveo config file under **both App_Config/Include/Coveo and App_Config/Modules/Coveo folders**.

Among all Coveo configuration values, there is one that is more sensible when doing this. I'm talking about the `<sitecorePassword>` you can find in the `Coveo.SearchProvider.Custom.config` file. This value is **stored encrypted** and the encryption key is not in any configuration file.

That's why besides copying the config files you should also make sure you have the `CORE_ENCRYPTIONKEYS` (or `ENCRYPTIONKEYS` if not using SC 9.x) entry on your `core` database (or `WEB_ENCRYPTIONKEYS` in the `web` if you don't have **core** as part of your setup).

Comment: Hi , Hugo Thanks for your reply . I am using Sitecore 8.1 with Coveo 4 on premise. My biggest worry is any changes in my local version (copied ) shouldn't affect actual the original version .Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To add onto that, if you navigate to the Properties table in the Web DB, you will find an entry (if this is coveo for Sitecore 10+, not sure about lower versions) with Key=WEB_ENCRYPTIONKEYS. I did some digging on the encryption method Coveo uses and came up with a handy decryptor in case you need it

```
void Main()
{
    const string encryptedPassword = "";
    const string secret = "";

    var keys = GetKeys(secret);
    var deccryptedPasswordBytes = DecryptData(encryptedPassword, keys);

    var decrpyptedPassword = "";
    using(var stream = new MemoryStream(deccryptedPasswordBytes)) 
    {
        using(var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
        {
            decrpyptedPassword = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }       
    }

    decrpyptedPassword.Dump();
}

public byte[] Decode(string p_EncodedValue)
{
    return Convert.FromBase64String(p_EncodedValue);
}

public IEncryptionKeys GetKeys(string value)
{
    byte[] byteArray = Decode(value);

    byte[] numArray1 = new byte[32];
    byte[] numArray2 = new byte[16];
    
    using(var readStream = new MemoryStream(byteArray))
    {
        readStream.Read(numArray1, 0, numArray1.Length);
        readStream.Read(numArray2, 0, numArray2.Length);
    }
    
     return (IEncryptionKeys) new RijndaelEncryptionKeys(numArray1, numArray2);
}

public byte[] DecryptData(string password, IEncryptionKeys keys)
{
    byte[] passArray = Decode(password);
    
    using (Rijndael rijndael = Rijndael.Create())
    {
        rijndael.Key = keys.Key;
        rijndael.IV = keys.InitialisationVector;
        ICryptoTransform decryptor = rijndael.CreateDecryptor(rijndael.Key, rijndael.IV);
        using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(passArray))
        {
            using (CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream((Stream)memoryStream, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
            {
                using (MemoryStream destination = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    cryptoStream.CopyTo((Stream)destination);
                    return destination.ToArray();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```